# Swift XIB set label text

Tags: swift, xcode

I am attempting to create an 'alert banner' which displays a pin in a label within the alert banner.

I am calling the alert banner from 'ViewController.swift' with:

```
AlertBanner().Show(self, pin: 2520)
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value

The error is telling me that the AlertBannerText label is nil. I suspect it has not been created yet, but how would I go about waiting for the label to exist before populating it?

Any the code in the AlertBanner class:

```
class AlertBanner : UIView {

    @IBOutlet var AlertBannerText: UILabel!

    static weak var delegate: AlertBannerDelegate!

     func Show(_ vc: ViewController, pin: Int){

        var onlineBanner: UIView?
        var topPadding: CGFloat?
        var menuView: UIView?


      AlertBannerText.text = "\(pin)"

       let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        if let menu = vc.view.viewWithTag(3) { menuView = menu}

        onlineBanner = UINib(nibName: "AlertBanner", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? AlertBanner

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top }

        onlineBanner?.frame.origin.y = 0 - (window.frame.size.width / 7.5 + topPadding!)
        onlineBanner!.frame.size.width = window.frame.size.width
        onlineBanner!.frame.size.height = window.frame.size.width / 5
        onlineBanner!.tag = 2
        vc.view.insertSubview(onlineBanner!, belowSubview: menuView!)

        if let banner = vc.view.viewWithTag(2) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                banner.frame.origin.y = window.frame.size.width / 7.5 + topPadding!

            }, completion: nil)
        }


    }
```

Comment: There are many problems in your code. You should not use tags, views should not be just added to a controller, the controller should do that. Unnecessary optionals, `var` that should be `let` and so on.

Comment: Hi Sulthan, thanks for the feedback, I was attempting to make a class which would add an alert view with a simple call to the alertViewClass with a view to prevent writing the same code in each place I wanted to present the view, is this in inadvisable way of doing this? How should I be approaching this? many thanks :)

Comment: Architecture is something that's pretty hard to learn and teach. However, you should definitely start with improving your code style. For example, your function and variable names should start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `func show` , `var alertBannerText`. Why do you declare variables at the start of the function? Declare them only when you need them, e.g. `let onlineBanner = ` or even `guard let onlineBanner = UINib(...).instantiate(...) else { return }` to also remove  the optionals.

Comment: ok, thanks for the pointers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this

```
AlertBanner().//////
```

creates an instance without the layout , hence all outlets are nil , you need to create an instance with

```
class func getInstance() -> AlertBanner {

  let onlineBanner = UINib(nibName: "AlertBanner", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! AlertBanner
  return onlineBanner 
}
```

and then

```
 AlertBanner.getInstance().//////
```